# what (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) ? service nginx status

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I just found an error in the state of nginx.
This error does not prevent anything.
It does not give me problems.
Everything is started correctly.
Nginx -t
It did not return any syntax errors.

I only see it in the nginx status sale.
Service nginx status.
Or
Systemctl status nginx

Error:

```
systemctl status nginx
* nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-02-11 20:55:04 UTC; 5min ago
  Process: 25343 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 25710 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25706 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25715 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 2.0M
      CPU: 49ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           |-25715 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           `-25720 nginx: worker process                           

Feb 11 20:55:04 Singapore-ap-southeast systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 11 20:55:04 Singapore-ap-southeast systemd[1]: nginx.service: PID 25363 read from file /run/nginx.pid does not exist or is a zombie.
Feb 11 20:55:04 Singapore-ap-southeast systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

---

Error resulted.

I simply did:

```
Service nginx stop
```

And then start with the new system:

```
systemctl start nginx
```

And now he devoured me.

```
    * nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-02-11 21:41:00 UTC; 1min 43s ago
  Process: 20928 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20941 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20938 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20944 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 2.0M
      CPU: 22ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           |-20944 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           `-20945 nginx: worker process                           

Feb 11 21:41:00 Singapore-ap-southeast systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 11 21:41:00 Singapore-ap-southeast systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Feb 11 21:41:00 Singapore-ap-southeast systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

The only bad thing I see is the

```
PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
```

But all functional.

Answer (score 2):

```
Process: 25343 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

This line is saying that the quit process failed.(see the `--stop` option in there).

It simply means that it failed to stop, which most likely means that it wasn't running in the first place :)

The only thing you really need to worry about is seeing the service as not running once you've attempted to start it.